# Flutter placeholder for CachedNetworkImage

Tags: flutter

I am using `cached_network_image` package to display images and have placeholders while being loaded. Below is the error that I have and the widget where I use `CachedNetworkImage`.

```
The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'
```

```
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: "https://cdn....${item.id}/${item.imageName}.jpg",
              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: imageProvider,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
```

Searched a bit and I found similar question in this Github thread and an answer that explains that `CachedNetworkImage` provides a callback that I can use to return image provider. I tried that example but still have that error.

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/177#issuecomment-510359079

I noticed that question in Github thread has `The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'.` error, while mine is `The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.`

Could anyone tell me please what I am doing wrong.

Comment: CNI(...,child:Container)

Comment: when the image loaded it will render widget

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CachedNetworkImage` need to wrap outside **Widget** you want to render

remove

```
Container(...,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      image: DecorationImage(
        image:
```

keep

```
CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: "https://cdn....${item.id}/${item.imageName}.jpg",
          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: imageProvider,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
        ),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
```

Because argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter `image`is type 'ImageProvider' in `Container`

Comment: But what if the requirement is such that i need to display cachedImage inside decoration. Because the child of container needs to have another widget

Answer (score 2):

Use `CachedNetworkImageProvider()` when you want it inside a Decoration Image

```
DecorationImage(
             image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                    Assets.image1,
                    errorListener: () {
                      const Text(
                        'Loading',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: AppColors.greyDeepColor,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )),
```

If you want to use it as a stand alone widget and not inside a decoration image , thats when you will use `CachedNetworkImage()`.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: Assets.image2`enter code here`,
                    progressIndicatorBuilder:
                        (context, url, downloadProgress) => const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Loading',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: AppColors.greyDeepColor,
                          fontSize: 10,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.error,
                        color: AppColors.blueColor,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use cached_network_image inside decoration image instead use it directly or as a child of the container and you can customize your image inside the image builder property of cached_network_image.

Reason: cached_network_image is not a type of Imageprovider widget.